# Returning an empty string : efficient way in c++

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have 2 ways of returning an empty string from a function.

1)

```
std::string get_string()
{
   return "";
}
```

2)

```
std::string get_string()
{
   return std::string();
}
```

which one is more efficient and why?

Comment: Neither. Use `return {};`.

Comment: And how does this relate to C?

Comment: This falls into the realm of useless micro-optimization that your compiler will optimize away using RVO and copy elision.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you elaborate why?

Comment: Because it's direct initialization with the default constructor, rather than copy initialization (from a possibly dynamically evaluated constructor). The default constructor may be implemented as no-allocation constexpr if your implementation is so inclined.

Comment: @Bowdzone: It's (possibly) more efficient than the first since it simply default-constructs the string rather than reading the value of a string literal; and more efficient than the second since it requires less typing.

Comment: @KerrekSB no different in practice than returning `std::string`. see my answer

Comment: "the realm of useless micro-optimization" Perhaps that's the real question.  How much does it cost to create a string from a char * and is it important?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Gcc 7.1 -O3 these are all identical, godbolt.org/z/a-hc1d – jterm Apr 25 at 3:27

### Original answer:

Did some digging. Below is an example program and the relevant assembly:

Code:

```
#include <string>

std::string get_string1(){ return ""; }

std::string get_string2(){ return std::string(); }

std::string get_string3(){ return {}; }           //thanks  Kerrek SB

int main()
{
    get_string1();
    get_string2();
    get_string3();
}
```

Assembly:

```
__Z11get_string1v:
LFB737:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 3, -8
    subl    $40, %esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    movl    48(%esp), %ebx
    leal    31(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %ebx, (%esp)
    call    __ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
    addl    $40, %esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    popl    %ebx
    .cfi_restore 3
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
    ret $4
    .cfi_endproc

__Z11get_string2v:
LFB738:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    movl    $__ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE+12, (%eax)
    ret $4
    .cfi_endproc

__Z11get_string3v:
LFB739:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    movl    $__ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE+12, (%eax)
    ret $4
    .cfi_endproc
```

This was compiled with `-std=c++11 -O2`.

You can see that there is quite a lot more work for the `return "";` statement and comparably little for `return std::string` and `return {};` (these two are identical).

As Frerich Raabe said, when passing an empty `C_string`, it still needs to do processing on it, instead of just allocating memory.  It seems that this can't be optimised away (at least not by GCC)

So the answer is to definitely use:

```
return std::string();
```

or

```
return {};   //(c++11)
```

Although unless you are returning *a lot* of empty strings in performance critical code (logging I guess?), the difference is going to still be insignificant.

Comment: Maybe this needs an update as of 2017 all of the three possibilities returns yields the same asm result so there's no issues about returning an "" or an std::string{} or {}. Tested on compiler explorer for clang & gcc

Comment: @TomazCanabrava I should have noted gcc version at the time...  If you want to provide clang and gcc versions that you tested, I'll note this in the answer.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava actually, when I try gcc and clang with the above, I get similar results (gcc 7.1/clang4.0.0).  interestingly enough, Visual studio (2015) provides results that are consistent between each version, but does more work in all cases.

Comment: Also worth noting is that `return {};` is a C++ extension, so `return std::string();` should be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

The latter version is never slower than the first. The first version calls the `std::string` constructor taking a C string, which then has to compute the length of the string first. Even though that's fast to do for an empty string, it's certainly not faster than not doing it at all.

Comment: As it is a constant that is being returned, is the length calculation not optimised away by the compiler? If not, could it be?

Comment: @Baldrickk He's calling the one argument constructor of `std::string`.  I don't think that there are many (if any) compilers that are clever enough to deduce that the one argument constructor is the equivalent of the constructor taking both a pointer and a size, provided it passes one less than the size of the string literal (which has a trailing `'\0'`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: some compilers optimise `strlen()` on a string literal - I requested the feature be added to SparcWorks C++ more than a decade ago - don't know if they ever did it - GCC already did it back then.  Still - I wouldn't necessarily expect a C++ implementation to use `strlen`... never know though.

Comment: @JamesKanze Confirmed what you said. See my answer.